# Outlook printing

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, printing

I am trying to print a schedule in the Outlook Calendar that will not include a specific event appointment for the day.

For instance if I add an appointment for 2:00 PM and 1:00 PM and print a calendar, it should not print anything prior to 1:00 PM since those events already happened.

Is there any way to accomplish this?